# How to set a particular range so that it takes the value of that range and run in python

Tags: python, loops, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

have this python code that has a link present

```
driver.get('https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=1')
```

in the place of `brand=55` there should be forloop range so that it takes values from (1-500) and run the code .

code :

```
#Importing packages
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/1/chromedriver.exe')


driver.get('https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=1')

try:

    click_more = True

    while click_more:


        time.sleep(5)
        element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary.btn-lg").click()


except : 
....
```

how to add for loop so that it loops in range from (1-500).

like

```
driver.get('https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=1')
driver.get('https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=2')
driver.get('https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=3')
driver.get('https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=4')
driver.get('https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=5')
driver.get('https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=6')
```

......
   ......
   .....
   .....
    driver.get('https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=500')

Answer (score 1):

If you are in python version 3.5+, you can use an f-string:

```py
for i in range(1, 501):
    site = f'https://simpletire.com/catalog?select1&brand={i}'
    driver.get(site)
    # rest of code
```

Otherwise, you can use % formatting syntax:

```py
for i in range(1, 501):
    site = 'https://simpletire.com/catalog?select1&brand=%d' % i
    driver.get(site)
    # rest of code
```

Or the `str.format` syntax

```py
for i in range(1, 501):
    site = 'https://simpletire.com/catalog?select1&brand={}'.format(i)
    driver.get(site)
    # rest of code
```

Comment: Could still use the `.format` notation (which has more power than the python2 string formatting),

Comment: question: could this work?
    `for i in range(1, 5001):
            driver.get('https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=' + str(i))`

Comment: @AmosBordowitz yes you could, it's about as fast as `str.format`, though much slower than f-strings in timing results

Comment: timing is not relevant to the question whatsoever and ruins what would have otherwise been a good answer.